# RAM used by apps doesn't sum up vs free RAM, why?

Tags: ram

I ran some commands (in a script to be fast) and got this:

```
$ ps -A | wc -l
513

$ echo "$((`ps -A -o rss |tr "\n" +`0))"
4368208

$ free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        5993608     5157844      132848       42616      702916      519028
Swap:      21030892     5276136    15754756

$ cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:        5993608 kB
MemFree:          132996 kB
MemAvailable:     519176 kB
Buffers:           83384 kB
Cached:           514368 kB
SwapCached:       422808 kB
Active:           392060 kB
Inactive:        1572336 kB
Active(anon):     106632 kB
Inactive(anon):  1312656 kB
Active(file):     285428 kB
Inactive(file):   259680 kB
Unevictable:       27084 kB
Mlocked:           27084 kB
SwapTotal:      21030892 kB
SwapFree:       15754756 kB
Dirty:               264 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       1190852 kB
Mapped:          1107036 kB
Shmem:             42616 kB
KReclaimable:     105164 kB
Slab:             291468 kB
SReclaimable:     105164 kB
SUnreclaim:       186304 kB
KernelStack:       19376 kB
PageTables:        58636 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    24027696 kB
Committed_AS:   14543756 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      117308 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
Percpu:             7072 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
FileHugePages:         0 kB
FilePmdMapped:         0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
Hugetlb:               0 kB
DirectMap4k:     5936768 kB
DirectMap2M:      335872 kB
DirectMap1G:           0 kB
```

where did 789636 kB (5157844-4368208) go?
My final goal is to determine what is using that RAM and if it can be freed.
I need to be able to list what is using that RAM if possible.
Is there a better `ps` command parameters for that?

related:
[RAM usage doesn't add up? (Free+used < total)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39721/ram-usage-doesnt-add-up-freeused-total)
[Substantial portion of memory used is not accounted for by user processes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/210831/substantial-portion-of-memory-used-is-not-accounted-for-by-user-processes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kernel itself uses some ram, but most of it is in that 702,916k of buffers/cache.